# The Stack Exchange Inbox shows an incorrect number of pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox

Currently, there are 193 pages in my inbox.

However, it has no entries on the last page. The last page with entries is 191 for me.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Even the pagination disappears. When I press my browser's back button, it navigates to the previous page on Stack Overflow

This could easily be fixed with `history.pushState()`.

Comment: Same for me - even the navigation is gone, so it's hard to go to the 2nd-to-last page.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: you can't even press back button

Comment: You can, but it doesn't get you to where you'd expect `:-)`

Comment: @HendrikVogt: okay, I said it wrong :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a bug in the back-end with counts in SQL vs counts in redis and overlap between the two...it will be fixed in the next build of that service (in the next half hour or so).